# Python. Adding multiple items to keys in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to build a dict from a set of unique values to serve as the keys and a zipped list of tuples to provide the items.

```
set = ("a","b","c")

lst 1 =("a","a","b","b","c","d","d")
lst 2 =(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,)

zip = [("a",1),("a",2),("b",3),("b",3),("c",4),("d",5)("d",6)

dct = {"a":1,2 "b":3,3 "c":4 "d":5,6}
```

But I am getting:

```
dct = {"a":1,"b":3,"c":4,"d":5}
```

here is my code so far:

```
#make two lists 

rtList = ["EVT","EVT","EVT","EVT","EVT","EVT","EVT","HIL"]
raList = ["C64G","C64R","C64O","C32G","C96G","C96R","C96O","RA96O"]

# make a set of unique codes in the first list

routes = set()
for r in rtList:
    routes.add(r)

#zip the lists

RtRaList = zip(rtList,raList)
#print RtRaList

# make a dictionary with list one as the keys and list two as the values

SrvCodeDct = {}

for key, item in RtRaList:
    for r in routes:
        if r == key:
            SrvCodeDct[r] = item

for key, item in SrvCodeDct.items():
    print key, item
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need any of that. Just use a `collections.defaultdict`.

```
import collections

rtList = ["EVT","EVT","EVT","EVT","EVT","EVT","EVT","HIL"]
raList = ["C64G","C64R","C64O","C32G","C96G","C96R","C96O","RA96O"]

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for k,v in zip(rtList, raList):
    d[k].append(v)
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Didn't know about that module.

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve this using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method as:

```
my_dict = {}
for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    my_dict.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
```

which will return value of `my_dict` as:

```
>>> my_dict
{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [4], 'b': [3, 3], 'd': [5, 6]}
```

OR, use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as mentioned by TigerhawkT3.

---

**Issue with your code:** You are not making the check for existing `key`. Everytime you do `SrvCodeDct[r] = item`, you are updating the previous value of `r` key with `item` value. In order to fix this, you have to add `if` condition as:

```
l1 = ("a","a","b","b","c","d","d")
l2 = (1,2,3,3,4,5,6,)

my_dict = {}
for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    if i in my_dict:          # your `if` check 
        my_dict[i].append(j)  # append value to existing list
    else:
        my_dict[i] = [j]  


>>> my_dict
{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [4], 'b': [3, 3], 'd': [5, 6]}
```

However this code can be simplified using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (as mentioned by TigerhawkT3), OR using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method as:

```
my_dict = {}
for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    my_dict.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
```

Comment: @ Moinududdin I like this answer too, especially because you don't have to import collections, but as both are good and I already chose TigerhawkT3's, I'll stick to that. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

In `dict`s, all keys are unique, and each key can only have one value.

The easiest way to solve this is have the value of the dictionary be a `list`, as to emulate what is called a multimap. In the list, you have all the elements that is mapped-to by the key.

EDIT:

You might want to check out this PyPI package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multidict

Under the hood, however, it probably works as described above.

Afaik, there is nothing built-in that supports what you are after.